# DeadlineExceededException when creating tasks on startup

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a Spring Boot 2.4.5 application deployed on Google Cloud Run (image created with Jib). On startup I want to create a Cloud Task but I get a `DeadlineExceededException`.

If I run the task creation code but triggered by an HTTP request, the task is created. And the task that was supposed to be created on startup is also created. It's like something is missing at the startup that prevents task to be created.

**The startup event**

```
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void doSomethingAfterStartup()  {
    LOGGER.info("ApplicationReadyEvent");
    String message = "GCP New Instance Start " + Instant.now();
    cloudTasksService.createTask("xxxx", "us-central1", "xxxx", message, 60);
}
```

**The task creation code**

```
public void createTask(String projectId, String locationId, String queueId, String message, Integer delay) throws IOException {
    try (CloudTasksClient client = CloudTasksClient.create()) {
        LOGGER.info("Client created");
        String url = "xxxxxxxxx";
        String payload = String.format("{ \"text\": \"%s\"}", message);

        String queuePath = QueueName.of(projectId, locationId, queueId).toString();
        Instant eta = Instant.now().plusSeconds(delay);
        Task.Builder taskBuilder =
                Task.newBuilder()
                        .setScheduleTime(Timestamp.newBuilder().setSeconds(eta.getEpochSecond()).build())
                        .setHttpRequest(
                                HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                                        .setBody(ByteString.copyFrom(payload, Charset.defaultCharset()))
                                        .setUrl(url)
                                        .setHttpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                                        .build());
        LOGGER.info("TaskBuilder ready");
        Task task = client.createTask(queuePath, taskBuilder.build());
        LOGGER.info("Task created: {}", task.getName());
    }
}
```

**The HTTP endpoint**

```
@GetMapping("/tasks")
public ResponseEntity<Void> task(@RequestParam Integer delay) throws IOException {
    cloudTasksService.createTask("xxxx", "us-central1", "xxxx", "using HTTP request", delay);
    return ResponseEntity.accepted().build();
}
```

**The exception**

```
com.google.api.gax.rpc.DeadlineExceededException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded after 5.200272920s. 
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:51)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97)
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:68)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1074)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1213)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.addListener(AbstractFuture.java:724)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingListenableFuture.addListener(ForwardingListenableFuture.java:45)
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutureToListenableFuture.addListener(ApiFutureToListenableFuture.java:52)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.addCallback(Futures.java:1047)
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures.addCallback(ApiFutures.java:63)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable.futureCall(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:67)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable$1.futureCall(UnaryCallable.java:126)
    at com.google.api.gax.tracing.TracedUnaryCallable.futureCall(TracedUnaryCallable.java:75)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable$1.futureCall(UnaryCallable.java:126)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable.futureCall(UnaryCallable.java:87)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable.call(UnaryCallable.java:112)
    at com.google.cloud.tasks.v2.CloudTasksClient.createTask(CloudTasksClient.java:1915)
    at com.google.cloud.tasks.v2.CloudTasksClient.createTask(CloudTasksClient.java:1885)
    at com.sps.playground.CloudTasksService.createTask(CloudTasksService.java:55)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the workers are not ready when the task is being queued. I'd recommend creating tasks on startup as this can happen often due to workers not passing the readiness check when the task is being processed, and then it fails. That wold also explain why the task runs normally when triggered by HTTP.

You can tackle this by decreasing the time of your startup following the [recommendations](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tips/general#starting_services_quickly). Also,   as you are using Java with Springboot, it may be worth checking [Reducing startup tasks](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tips/java#reduce-tasks) recommendations as well.